# How to make glassy quare button with drawable on top?

Tags: android, button, styling

I want to make a glassy button with application icon drawable on top.
I tried `Button`, set `android:background` to the glassy drawable, and attached an application icon using `drawableTop`, however, the application icon doesn't center in the button

So I tried to use `ImageButton` but `ImageButton` doesn't have `android:background` and that means I can't set the glassy drawable and app icon together.

- How can I make glassy drawable using XML?
- How can I apply both backgrounds and center the app icon?
- The button is `75x75` dp

Comment: `ImageButton` does have an `android:background` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the view for your requirement

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/android"
        android:text="Android"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"/>
```

I have tried this with 75 * 75 dp drawable. It is aligning to the center. You can also set background to the button for glassy look. To do it so use [this](http://angrytools.com/android/button/)
tool to generate background drawable for your need and customize accordingly

Here is the glassy button background that i have created for you. Set this in your `android:background=@drawable/glassybutton`

**glassybutton.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
                    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="10dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <gradient android:angle="270"
                        android:startColor="#80FFFFFF"
                        android:endColor="#20FFFFFF"/>
                    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ImageView`, use `android:background` for your drawable and `android:src` for your icon and you can change the gravity of the icon within the view by `android:gravity`